# Почтовый сервер на VPS

Tags: postfix, email, vps, django

Здраствуйте!
Для отправки писем с активацией учетной записи + информировании желающих пользователей о новостях проекта, необходимо поднять почтовый сервер.
Установил postfix - по этой инструкции - http://dedicatesupport.com/archives/7
Прописал в settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_EMAIL_UNIQUE = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'mydomain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-reply@mydomain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'no-reply@mydomain.com'
```

Делаю регистрацию через django-registration (должно отправляться письмо с подтверждением). Django выдает ошибку:

```
SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

OS: Fedora

Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Comment: Уберите проблему из кода. Судя по виду не поддерживается расширение для авторизации по SMTP на вашем почтовом сервере или возможно не подключен. И еще вопрос почему не CentOS?

Comment: Проблема в коде моего скрипта? Как проверить что поддерживается расширения для авторизации по SMTP?

Почему не CentOS - не знаю, так мне сделали при заказе vps.

Comment: Для рассылки писем активаций нет смысла поднимать свой почтовый сервер: это ненужная трата ресурсов VPS. Гораздо проще и удобнее использовать внешние службы, например, GMail или Яндекс.Почта. Посмотрите pdd.yandex.ru - там подключение почты на домен за несколько минут делается.

Comment: На gmail к примеру ограничение до 500 писем в сутки. Я надеюсь что мне этого не хватит =)

Comment: Письма активации обычно рассылаются при помощи smtp патча на php.

Comment: У меня php нет. =) Только python.

Comment: На питон тоже наверняка есть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы настраиваете не публичный SMTP, а SMTP чисто для сайта, то нет смысла делать в нём авторизацию по паролям. Уберите любую авторизацию из postfix (в и итоге отправка письма будет происходить чуть быстрее) и сделайте сервис доступным только через localhost (средствами самого postfix + если вам не нужно получать ответы, то и средствами iptables). Таким образом всё будет намного проще.
Только вот я не уверен, что с активностью более 500 писем в сутки, вас не занесут сразу же в спам-листы. Ну и VPS-ка должна быть уже не хиленькой с таким раскладом...